# Sagemath: why is an inequality not getting converted to a Boolean?

Tags: types, boolean, sage

I do not know whether this is a Sage or a Python issue, but here it is.

```
var('k')
awPkf(k) = k+7
awPkpf(k) = k+5
batkola(k)=2*(k+1)*awPkpf(k)/((k-2)*awPkf(k))
```

When I then type "batkola(4)", I get 45/11, as expected.
However, when I type "batkola(4)<=4", I get "(45/11) < 4", not "False".
When I type:

```
("no","yes")[batkola(4)<=4]
```

I get

```
TypeError: unable to convert (45/11) <= 4 to an integer
```

in reply.
(Note that ("no",yes")[False] returns "no", as it should.)
What is going on and what should I do?

Comment: What does the `ratkola` function return?  Can't find any doc on it -- is it returning some weird object that overloads the comparison operator to return a string instead of a bool?

Comment: Sorry, that was I typo for "batkola".

Comment: same question re `batkola` then

Comment: It's defined above!

Comment: that doesn't look like a Python function definition -- there should be a `lambda` or a `def` in there...

Comment: Ah, it's a Sage thing, then.

Answer (score 0):

QQ(batkola(4)) does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate `type(batkola(4))`: you will get

```
sage: type(batkola(4))
<class 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression'>
```

Sage is (intentionally) unwilling to evaluate inequalities involving symbolic expressions, but you can force it by using the `bool` function:

```
sage: batkola(4) <= 4
(45/11) <= 4
sage: bool(batkola(4) <= 4)
False
```

So you can do

```
sage: ("no","yes")[bool(batkola(4)<=4)]
'no'
```